# How to convert String to long in Java?

Tags: java, string

I got a simple question in Java: How can I convert a `String` that was obtained by `Long.toString()` to `long`?

Comment: [5 ways with examples](http://javadevnotes.com/java-string-to-long-examples) for how to convert string to long in Java

Comment: Please refer to this one: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String,%20int)

Answer (score 755, accepted):

Use [`Long.parseLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
 Long.parseLong("0", 10)        // returns 0L
 Long.parseLong("473", 10)      // returns 473L
 Long.parseLong("-0", 10)       // returns 0L
 Long.parseLong("-FF", 16)      // returns -255L
 Long.parseLong("1100110", 2)   // returns 102L
 Long.parseLong("99", 8)        // throws a NumberFormatException
 Long.parseLong("Hazelnut", 10) // throws a NumberFormatException
 Long.parseLong("Hazelnut", 36) // returns 1356099454469L
 Long.parseLong("999")          // returns 999L
```

Comment: what about "Lunch/Dinner" ?

Answer (score 154):

To convert a **String** to a **Long** (object), use `Long.valueOf(String s).longValue();`

See [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

Comment: @Belgi. No, it returns `java.lang.Long`

Comment: @Belgi - Long.valueOf returns a Long, not a string.

Comment: @MikeDaniels, Because this is a very indirect way of doing it. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String), it returns a Long **object** not the primitive long.

Comment: Long.valueOf(String s) gives a Long (object) and Long.valueOf(String s).longValue() gives the long (primitive).

Answer (score 32):

```
public class StringToLong {

   public static void main (String[] args) {

      // String s = "fred";    // do this if you want an exception

      String s = "100";

      try {
         long l = Long.parseLong(s);
         System.out.println("long l = " + l);
      } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
         System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**There are a few ways to convert `String` to `long`:**

1)

```java
long l = Long.parseLong("200");
```

2. 

```java
String numberAsString = "1234";
long number = Long.valueOf(numberAsString).longValue();
```

3. 

```java
String numberAsString = "1234";
Long longObject = new Long(numberAsString);
long number = longObject.longValue();
```

**We can shorten to:**

```java
String numberAsString = "1234";
long number = new Long(numberAsString).longValue();
```

**Or just**

```java
long number = new Long("1234").longValue();
```

4. Using Decimal format:

```java
String numberAsString = "1234";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");
try {
    long number = decimalFormat.parse(numberAsString).longValue();
    System.out.println("The number is: " + number);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println(numberAsString + " is not a valid number.");
}
```

Answer (score 14):

[Long.valueOf(String s)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) - obviously due care must be taken to protect against non-numbers if that is possible in your code.

Answer (score 8):

The best approach is [`Long.valueOf(str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf-long-) as it relies on [`Long.valueOf(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf-long-) which uses an internal cache making it more efficient since it will reuse if needed the cached instances of `Long` going from `-128` to `127` included.

> Returns a `Long` instance representing the specified long value. If a
>   new Long instance is not required, this method should generally be
>   used in preference to the constructor `Long(long)`, as this method is
>   likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by
>   caching frequently requested values. Note that unlike the
>   corresponding method in the Integer class, this method is not required
>   to cache values within a particular range.

Thanks to [**auto-unboxing**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) allowing to convert a wrapper class's instance into its corresponding primitive type, the code would then be:

```
long val = Long.valueOf(str);
```

Please note that the previous code can still throw a `NumberFormatException` if the provided `String` doesn't match with a signed `long`.

Generally speaking, it is a good practice to use the `static` factory method `valueOf(str)` of a wrapper class like `Integer`, `Boolean`, `Long`, ... since most of them reuse instances whenever it is possible making them potentially more efficient in term of memory footprint than the corresponding `parse` methods or constructors.

---

Excerpt from [**Effective Java**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) `Item 1` written by **Joshua Bloch**:

> You can often avoid creating unnecessary objects by using *static
>   factory methods* (Item 1) in preference to constructors on immutable
>   classes that provide both. For example, the static factory method
>   `Boolean.valueOf(String)` is almost always preferable to the
>   constructor `Boolean(String)`. The constructor creates a new object
>   each time it’s called, while the static factory method is never
>   required to do so and won’t in practice.

Comment: It's worth noting that auto-unboxing is "desugared" by the compiler into, for the case of long -> Long, Long.valueOf(primitiveLong). So  `Long number = Long.valueOf("123")`, `Long number = Long.parseLong("123")` and `Long number = Long.valueOf(Long.parseString("123")` all end up doing pretty much the same thing.

What you *do* want to be careful about is not calling constructors of the boxed primitive classes - that can be wasteful. So don't write `Long number = new Long(parseLong("123"))`

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple, use
`Long.valueOf(String s);`

For example:

```java
String s;
long l;

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
s=sc.next();
l=Long.valueOf(s);
System.out.print(l);
```

You're done!!!

Answer (score 1):

For those who switched to Kotlin just use
`string.toLong()`
That will call `Long.parseLong(string)` under the hood

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to check if the String to be converted to Long
**is not null** and **is really Long** to avoid **`NumberFormatException`**.
To do that the best way is to create a new method like this:

```
    public static Long convertStringToLong(String str) {
        try {
            return Long.valueOf(str);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert String to Long Value you need to use

```
Long.valueOf((AppSessionManager.getContactNo())).longValue();
```

you can use try-catch for NumberFormatException

```
 try {
     Long.valueOf((AppSessionManager.getContactNo())).longValue();
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
     System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using the Map with out generic, then you need to convert the value into String and then try to convert to Long. Below is sample code

```
    Map map = new HashMap();

    map.put("name", "John");
    map.put("time", "9648512236521");
    map.put("age", "25");

    long time = Long.valueOf((String)map.get("time")).longValue() ;
    int age = Integer.valueOf((String)  map.get("aget")).intValue();
    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(age);
```