# Whats going on behind the scenes with method - public static long parseLong(String s,int radix)

Tags: java, radix

I need to generate a consistent unique Long based on the name of the package. Instead of using "Convert string to long" in Eclipse I think I can achieve the same task at run time by using method public static long parseLong(String s,int radix) ?

I think I need to use something like -
Long.parseLong("Hazelnut", 36) returns 1356099454469L

Which I got from question - [How to convert String to long in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693324/converting-string-to-long-in-java)

Why do I need to set radix to 36 when converting a String that contains characters ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're basically to treat it as a number in base 36. So for example, the string "012" would mean 2 + 1 * 36 + 0 * 36<sup>2</sup>. When you run out of digits, you go to letters - so "ABC" would mean 12<sub>from 'C'</sub> + 11<sub>from 'B'</sub> * 36 + 10<sub>from 'A'</sub> * 36<sup>2</sup>.

If you understand how hex works, it's the same except using all the characters in the Latin alphabet.

It'll fail for anything not in 0-9, A-Z, a-z though - and it'll also fail for reasonably long strings; `long` only works up to 2<sup>63</sup> which you'll get past reasonably quickly in base 36. "Hazelnut12345" fails, for example. Oh, and this is case-insensitive, so the value for "foo" is the same as for "FOO" - does that fail your uniqueness requirement?

Fundamentally you've only got 2<sup>64</sup> `long` values to play with, so unless your package names are pretty restricted you're not going to work out a unique mapping.

Comment: I can convert a decimal number / binary to hex, but im a little confused when it comes to Strings. How are you working out - the string "012" would mean 2 + 1 * 36 + 0 * 36(squared) ? It does'nt need to be case sensitive.

Comment: @user470184: Think about what it would mean if the "012" were in base 10 - it would mean 2 + 1 * 10 + 0 * (10 squared). Now take the 10, and remember that you're asking it to use base 36... and you'll see where I got the figures from.

Comment: Is "012" in base 10 not just 12 ?

Comment: @user470184: Yes, because 2 + 1*10 + 0*100 *is* 12.