# Cannot convert valid string to long

Tags: java, long-integer

I have String which cannot be converted to corresponding `Long` number using `Long.getLong(id)`. The value of string seems to be valid. Why returned `longId` is **null**?

Code:

`Long longId =  Long.getLong(id);`

Comment: Please post the text of your code here, instead of just the image of your code.

Comment: have you read the documentation for getLong? I don't think it does what you think it does.

Comment: You should read the documentation before asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting String to long in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693324/converting-string-to-long-in-java)

Comment: I don't understand all the down votes. Seems like 1 or 2 would suffice to let the guy and the world know it wasn't seen as such a good question, at which point why would two more people even view it? I did to see just how horrible it was since you don't see -4 very often. It's not such a good question; I agree, but let's not let pack mentality run too far amok. Heck, the guy got 4 answers from others instead of down votes. I just don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Long.valueOf(..)`. `Long.getLong(...)` is for different purpose:

`getLong(String nm)
Determines the long value of the system property with the specified name.`

Answer (score 3):

Use `Long.parseLong(id)` to convert from a String to a Long.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered on StackOverflow.  Please check the following URL:
[How to convert String to long in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693324/converting-string-to-long-in-java)
Credit to Mike Christensen and Josh Pinter for the original answer.

```
 Long.parseLong("0", 10)        // returns 0L
 Long.parseLong("473", 10)      // returns 473L
 Long.parseLong("-0", 10)       // returns 0L
 Long.parseLong("-FF", 16)      // returns -255L
 Long.parseLong("1100110", 2)   // returns 102L
 Long.parseLong("99", 8)        // throws a NumberFormatException
 Long.parseLong("Hazelnut", 10) // throws a NumberFormatException
 Long.parseLong("Hazelnut", 36) // returns 1356099454469L
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it: Long.parseLong("100")