# Continue after catching exception (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, exception

I want to convert an input string to long:

```
String inputStr = inputText.getText().toString();
Long inputNumber = Long.valueOf(inputStr);
// do something with inputNumber
```

However if the user input a string with alphabets the valueOf() will throw some exception to cause the program to crash.

On the other hand if I build a try-catch block around valueOf(), I get a "cannot resolve symbol inputNumber" error. If I declare Long inputnumber outside the block I get a "this variable may not be initialized" error.

I want to just output an error message in a textView for incorrect inputStr, and continue the program as usual. How to do this?

Comment: try Long.parseLong(String s)

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693324/how-to-convert-string-to-long-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare and initialise inputNumber outside of try/catch:

```
Long inputNumber = null;
try {
    inputNumber = Long.valueOf(inputStr);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use **util class** and declare a **boolean method** and use it to check if entered number is number or not. This is **reusable** code.

```
public class StringUtil {

    public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        boolean returnVal = false;
        if (isNotEmpty(str)) {
            try {
                Long.parseLong(str);
                returnVal = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                returnVal = false;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

In your method

```
String inputStr = inputText.getText().toString();
Long inputNumber = null;
if (StringUtil.isNumeric(inputStr)) {
    inputNumber = Long.valueOf(inputStr);
    // do something with inputNumber
} else {
     // either notify user or whatever you want to do.
}
```

---

If you can use apache commons then you can use its [`NumberUtils.isNumber(String str)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String inputStr = inputText.getText().toString();
Long inputNumber = null;
if (NumberUtils.isNumber(inputStr)) {
    inputNumber = Long.valueOf(inputStr);
    // do something with inputNumber
}
```