# For loop an arraylist for each first two elements separated by comma in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve values and keep them in an arrayList from `request.getParametersValues`.

It goes something like this:

```
 String[] split = request.getParameterValues("arrayList");
 System.out.print(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Where the split should contain like this format: `[fileid1,hash1,fileid2,hash2,.....]`

It should comes in a pair where the first two are linked together.So now I want to use a for loop to update my table for the files based on the where constraint.

Something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<=split.length;i++) {

fileFacade.updateRecipient(fileid, hash, recipient);
}
```

In this case,there are two pairs of element so it will pass to the method fileid and hash and update the recipient value in table and proceed to do the same to update recipient for second pair of element.

The problem I am stuck is how to I split the array `split` to perform this?

### Edit

This is how my method looks:

```
public void updateRecipient(long fileid,String hash,String recipient){

    try {    
        String sql="UPDATE urllink SET Recipient='"+recipient+"'"+" WHERE URL='f0="+fileid+"&ts="+hash + "'";

        em.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

loop in steps of two

```
for(int i=0;i <split.length -1; i = i + 2) {  // NB not <=

    fileFacade.updateRecipient(split[i], split[i + 1], recipient);
}
```

Comment: I think you have a couple of typos in there, `i + i + 2` should be `i=i+2` and `split[1 + 1]` should be `split[i + 1]`. Also the loop should iterate up to `i < (split.length-1)` unless I'm mistaken

Comment: What does the first two parameter in the method do?

Comment: @Daredevil they are getting values from the array at index `i` and `i + 1`

Comment: so did you search as to how to convert a String to a Long?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693324/how-to-convert-string-to-long-in-java

Answer (score 2):

it should iterate from 0th index till (split.length-2)th index as we are accessing i+1 in the loop else will get indexoutofbound.

```
for(int i=0; i<split.length-1; i+=2) {
  fileFacade.updateRecipient(split[i], split[i+1], recipient);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Streamy" solutions:

```
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
  .limit(split.length >>> 1)
  .forEach(i -> fileFacade.updateRecipient(split[i], split[i+1], recipient));
```

or

```
IntStream.range(0, split.length >>> 1)
  .forEach(i -> fileFacade.updateRecipient(split[i*2], split[i*2+1], recipient));
```

or

```
private String fileId = null;

...

Arrays.stream(split).forEach(e -> {
  if (fileId == null) {
      fileId = e;
  } else {
    fileFacade.updateRecipient(fileId, e, recipient);
    fileId = null;
  }
});
```